# Changing the color of a visited a

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay so currently I have my `<a href=""></a>` wrapped around my entire primary div for images. How ever, I'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks on the box it will change the color to red from black.

I tried using

```
a: visited {
   background - color: red;
}
```

but I guess it wasn't that simple, so here is my code.. any help is very much appreciated, I'm assuming this can only be done in Javascript which I honestly know nothing about so..

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('singles', array( 'class'  => "img-responsive")); ?>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="ratings">
                        <p class="pull-right"> </p>
                        <p>
                            Watch Video
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve, the right side is what it currently is and what I want to change is to the right side when image is being clicked.

[image]

Styles for that are this

```
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4 px;
    margin - bottom: 20 px;
    line - height: 1.42857143;
    background - color: #212121;
    border: 1px solid # 191919;
}
```

Comment: `a:visted` -> typo -> `a:visited`

Comment: @JamesThorpe when changing it, it still does nothing.

Comment: There's something else going on then.  [Docs for `visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avisited) - there's absolutely no need for JS here.

Comment: @JamesThorpe view my edit please

Comment: @GolezTrol I think it's because I put my class there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actualy likely want to apply is the following:

```
a:active .thumbnail {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

This will make the thumbnail's background turn black when you begin to click the anchor.

If you want it to be changed based on browser history after being visited:

```
a:visited .thumbnail {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change`a:visted` to `a:visited`.